# Incrorrect font names within family

Tags: fonts, font-manager

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04.4.

Yesterday I purchased the full Vinque (by Ray Larabie) font family, which consists of 7 weights each with matching italics (list is sorted by ascending weight):

- Vinque Ultra Light `vinque_ul.otf`
- Vinque Ultra Light Italic `vinque_ul_it.otf`
- Vinque Extra Light `vinque_el.otf`
- Vinque Extra Light Italic `vinque_el_it.otf`
- Vinque Light `vinque_lt.otf`
- Vinque Light Italic `vinque_lt_it.otf`
- Vinque Semi Light `vinque_sl.otf`
- Vinque Semi Light Italic `vinque_sl_it.otf`
- Vinque Regular `vinque_rg.otf`
- Vinque Regular Italic `vinque_rg_it.otf`
- Vinque Semi Bold `vinque_sb.otf`
- Vinque Semi Bold Italic `vinque_sb_it.otf`
- Vinque Bold `vinque_bd.otf`
- Vinque Bold Italic `vinque_bd_it.otf`

There are TrueType files, but the issues don't seem relevant to file format.

Several attempts to uninstall and install them all from Dolphin resulted in a message saying one of them was already installed.  One or two at a time, I could install 10 of them without conflicts.

So I ran `fc-scan` on the `.otf` files and found a few items of interest.  Some of the weights were duplicated, others didn't match the weight constants defined in [fonts-conf](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html).

I've corresponded with Ray to fix the weight value issues, which allowed me to install all 14 fonts:

```
$ fc-list|grep -i Vinque
/usr/local/share/fonts/v/vinque_lt_it.otf: Vinque,Vinque Lt:style=Light Italic,Italic
/usr/local/share/fonts/v/vinque_rg.otf: Vinque,Vinque Rg:style=Regular
/usr/local/share/fonts/v/vinque_bd.otf: Vinque,Vinque Rg:style=Bold
/usr/local/share/fonts/v/vinque_sb_it.otf: Vinque,Vinque Sb:style=SemiBold Italic,Italic
/usr/local/share/fonts/v/vinque_sb.otf: Vinque,Vinque Sb:style=SemiBold,Regular
/usr/local/share/fonts/v/vinque_el.otf: Vinque,Vinque El:style=ExtraLight,Regular
/usr/local/share/fonts/v/vinque_ul.otf: Vinque,Vinque Ul:style=UltraLight,Regular
/usr/local/share/fonts/v/vinque_lt.otf: Vinque,Vinque Lt:style=Light,Regular
/usr/local/share/fonts/v/vinque_sl_it.otf: Vinque,Vinque Sl:style=SemiLight Italic,Italic
/usr/local/share/fonts/v/vinque_el_it.otf: Vinque,Vinque El:style=ExtraLight Italic,Italic
/usr/local/share/fonts/v/vinque_ul_it.otf: Vinque,Vinque Ul:style=UltraLight Italic,Italic
/usr/local/share/fonts/v/vinque_rg_it.otf: Vinque,Vinque Rg:style=Italic
/usr/local/share/fonts/v/vinque_sl.otf: Vinque,Vinque Sl:style=SemiLight,Regular
/usr/local/share/fonts/v/vinque_bd_it.otf: Vinque,Vinque Rg:style=Bold Italic
```

However, the the names I see in `kfontview` for the "* Light" weights do not reflect those fonts: "Light", "Semi Light", "Extra Light", and "Ultra Light" are all being called "Light" (Italic is properly attached to the italic fonts).  There are 4 "Light, Light Italic" pairs in the Font Manager system settings applet, while the preview panel correctly shows the 14 distinct fonts.

Below is filtered output from `fc-scan` for all the Light fonts, reordered by ascending weight with the derived names added as comments:

```
$ for F in `ls -1 vinque*l*.otf`; do echo $F;fc-scan $F|grep -iP '(vinque|style|slant|weight|width\b)'; done;
vinque_ul.otf # wrongly named "Vinque, Light"
    family: "Vinque"(s) "Vinque Ul"(s)
    style: "UltraLight"(s) "Regular"(s)
    stylelang: "en"(s) "en"(s)
    fullname: "VinqueUl-Regular"(s)
    slant: 0(i)(s)
    weight: 45(i)(s)
    width: 100(i)(s)
    file: "vinque_ul.otf"(s)
    postscriptname: "VinqueUl-Regular"(s)
vinque_ul_it.otf # wrongly named "Vinque, Light Italic"
    family: "Vinque"(s) "Vinque Ul"(s)
    style: "UltraLight Italic"(s) "Italic"(s)
    stylelang: "en"(s) "en"(s)
    fullname: "VinqueUl-Italic"(s)
    slant: 100(i)(s)
    weight: 45(i)(s)
    width: 100(i)(s)
    file: "vinque_ul_it.otf"(s)
    postscriptname: "VinqueUl-Italic"(s)
vinque_el.otf # wrongly named "Vinque, Light"
    family: "Vinque"(s) "Vinque El"(s)
    style: "ExtraLight"(s) "Regular"(s)
    stylelang: "en"(s) "en"(s)
    fullname: "VinqueEl-Regular"(s)
    slant: 0(i)(s)
    weight: 47(i)(s)
    width: 100(i)(s)
    file: "vinque_el.otf"(s)
    postscriptname: "VinqueEl-Regular"(s)
vinque_el_it.otf # wrongly named "Vinque, Light Italic"
    family: "Vinque"(s) "Vinque El"(s)
    style: "ExtraLight Italic"(s) "Italic"(s)
    stylelang: "en"(s) "en"(s)
    fullname: "VinqueEl-Italic"(s)
    slant: 100(i)(s)
    weight: 47(i)(s)
    width: 100(i)(s)
    file: "vinque_el_it.otf"(s)
    postscriptname: "VinqueEl-Italic"(s)
vinque_lt.otf # correctly named "Vinque, Light"
    family: "Vinque"(s) "Vinque Lt"(s)
    style: "Light"(s) "Regular"(s)
    stylelang: "en"(s) "en"(s)
    fullname: "VinqueLt-Regular"(s)
    slant: 0(i)(s)
    weight: 50(i)(s)
    width: 100(i)(s)
    file: "vinque_lt.otf"(s)
    postscriptname: "VinqueLt-Regular"(s)
vinque_lt_it.otf # correctly named "Vinque, Light Italic"
    family: "Vinque"(s) "Vinque Lt"(s)
    style: "Light Italic"(s) "Italic"(s)
    stylelang: "en"(s) "en"(s)
    fullname: "VinqueLt-Italic"(s)
    slant: 100(i)(s)
    weight: 50(i)(s)
    width: 100(i)(s)
    file: "vinque_lt_it.otf"(s)
    postscriptname: "VinqueLt-Italic"(s)
vinque_sl.otf # wrongly named "Vinque, Light"
    family: "Vinque"(s) "Vinque Sl"(s)
    style: "SemiLight"(s) "Regular"(s)
    stylelang: "en"(s) "en"(s)
    fullname: "VinqueSl-Regular"(s)
    slant: 0(i)(s)
    weight: 55(i)(s)
    width: 100(i)(s)
    file: "vinque_sl.otf"(s)
    postscriptname: "VinqueSl-Regular"(s)
vinque_sl_it.otf # wrongly named "Vinque, Light Italic"
    family: "Vinque"(s) "Vinque Sl"(s)
    style: "SemiLight Italic"(s) "Italic"(s)
    stylelang: "en"(s) "en"(s)
    fullname: "VinqueSl-Italic"(s)
    slant: 100(i)(s)
    weight: 55(i)(s)
    width: 100(i)(s)
    file: "vinque_sl_it.otf"(s)
    postscriptname: "VinqueSl-Italic"(s)
```

How `fontconfig` derives these names is far beyond my font knowledge, and even Ray is baffled.

What must be changed in the fonts themselves to result in the full family being named correctly?

Alternatively, is it possible to force the correct names via a file in `/etc/fonts/conf.d/` (which doesn't seem like the correct solution)?

Comment: Without having studied your question in detail, I suspect that the observations in [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1152363) might be relevant.